# Error When I'm Trying To Use My Website On Local

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I downloaded my cs-cart website with his database to use it offline, i followed the tutorial given by the helpdesk, using xampp or wamp, the database won't getting imported completely, there are less tables on local then on the host (103, 250), How can I resolve this problem? How to increase the number of tables on phpmyadmin? Can anyone help me to find a solution?

Comment: How are you exporting the database? Can you verify that all of the tables are in the export?

Comment: And do you get any errors from the import process? There shouldn't be a table limit you need to increase, no.